# antlr4 grammar fails to match initial identifier

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar that is failing on the first token. I've stripped it down some to reduce the choices, but still have the error:

line 1:0 mismatched input 'main' expecting {, '@', 'def', IDENTIFIER}

I expect the token 'main' to match IDENTIFIER, which has this lexical production:

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;

Why would that be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following is happening:

1. You have another rule in the grammar located before `IDENTIFIER` that also matches the input `main`.
2. You have a combined grammar (declared as `grammar T` instead of `parser grammar T` or `lexer grammar T`), where one of the parser rules contains the literal `'main'` which is causing a separate lexer rule to be implicitly created for this literal.

Comment: Ah, I think your #1 is probably it.